Find purchases in continuous days
I'm trying to use march_recognize to find customers who made purchases for 10 or more consecutive days.
Based in my sample data I was expecting that customer 1 would appear in my output but it doesn't. Can someone explain why I am not finding data. Additionally show me how to fix the query so it works.

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY  HH24:MI:SS.FF';

 
create table purchases(
  ORDER_ID NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
  customer_id   number, 
  PRODUCT_ID NUMBER, 
  QUANTITY NUMBER, 
  purchase_date timestamp
);

insert  into purchases (customer_id, product_id, quantity, purchase_date)
    select  1 customer_id, 102 product_id, 1 quantity,
             DATE '2024-04-08' + INTERVAL '13' HOUR + ((LEVEL-1) * INTERVAL '1 00:00:01' DAY TO SECOND)  * -1
           as purchase_date
    from    dual
    connect by level <= 15 UNION all
    select  2, 102, 1,
             DATE '2024-03-08' + INTERVAL '14' HOUR + ((LEVEL-1) * INTERVAL '1 00:00:00' DAY TO SECOND) * -1
   from    dual
   connect by level <= 5 UNION ALL 
select  3, 102, 1,
             DATE '2024-02-08' + INTERVAL '15' HOUR + ((LEVEL-1) * INTERVAL '0 23:59:59' DAY TO SECOND) * -1
   from    dual
   connect by level <= 5;


select * from purchases
match_recognize(
    partition by customer_id
    order by purchase_date
    measures
        first(purchase_date) as first_date,
        last(purchase_date) as last_date
    one row per match
    pattern(P{10,})
    define P as next(purchase_date)=purchase_date + interval '1' day
);



When doing "next(purchase_date)=purchase_date + interval '1' day" you are defining a too restrictive constraint because your dates have H:M:S...
You could add TRUNC() around your dates to get what you want.

As @p3consulting said, you're being too exact. You have created the interval between each row for customer 1 as one day and one second. With your current P if one purchase_date is 25-MAR-2024  12:59:46.000000 then adding 1 day to that gives 26-MAR-2024  12:59:46.000000, and there is no row with that value; the next one is 26-MAR-2024  12:59:47.000000 (one second later), so it does not match on equality.
If you define P as:
    define P as next(purchase_date) >= trunc(purchase_date) + interval '1' day
      and next(purchase_date) < trunc(purchase_date) + interval '2' day

then it will match any time on one day with any time on the following day.
select * from purchases
match_recognize(
    partition by customer_id
    order by purchase_date
    measures
        first(purchase_date) as first_date,
        last(purchase_date) as last_date
    one row per match
    pattern(P{10,})
    define P as next(purchase_date) >= trunc(purchase_date) + interval '1' day
      and next(purchase_date) < trunc(purchase_date) + interval '2' day
);




CUSTOMER_ID
FIRST_DATE
LAST_DATE




1
25-MAR-2024  12:59:46.000000
07-APR-2024  12:59:59.000000



fiddle


the last_date should be April 8 2024 or am I missing something.?

Your pattern is for at least 10 matches; but the row with April 8th does not match the define - for that date, there is no row where next(purchase_date) is the following day - so it is excluded. The last() only looks at the matching rows, so it doesn't see that date.
You can change the define to look backwards, and the pattern to have any date followed by at least 9 matches (to keep 10 consecutive values in total):
    pattern(start_date P{9,})
    define P as purchase_date >= prev(trunc(purchase_date)) + interval '1' day
      and purchase_date < prev(trunc(purchase_date)) + interval '2' day

which then gives:



CUSTOMER_ID
FIRST_DATE
LAST_DATE




1
25-MAR-2024  12:59:46.000000
08-APR-2024  13:00:00.000000



fiddle


I want to get the NUMBER of continuous days last_date-start_date

You can use aggregates as measures:
...
    measures
        first(purchase_date) as first_date,
        last(purchase_date) as last_date,
        count(trunc(purchase_date)) as count_dates
...




CUSTOMER_ID
FIRST_DATE
LAST_DATE
COUNT_DATES




1
25-MAR-2024  12:59:46.000000
08-APR-2024  13:00:00.000000
15



Or you can use the measures in your select list, instead of using select *:
select customer_id, first_date, last_date,
  trunc(last_date) - trunc(first_date) + 1 as count_dates
from purchases
...




CUSTOMER_ID
FIRST_DATE
LAST_DATE
COUNT_DATES




1
25-MAR-2024  12:59:46.000000
08-APR-2024  13:00:00.000000
15



fiddle

Alex, the last_date should be April 8 2024 or am I missing something.?

Yes - you got what you asked for, but that wasn't what you actually wanted *8-) Updated to show how to get that last date too.

Alex, hope you don't mind another follow up question but does MATCH_RECOGNIZE support a calculation I want to get the NUMBER of continuous days last_date-start_date

@Pugzly - yes, either as an extra measure or by manipulating the measures you already have. Added examples.
